# Op amp circuit gain analysis with multiple voltage source inputs

Tags: operational-amplifier, gain

[image]

I've been doing small signal gain calculations, but I'm just stumped on this question. I want to solve this question on my own so any tips on how to analyze op-amp circuits with 2 voltage sources attached would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Add up the two voltages on the left. Compare that with the voltage output on the right. Any thoughts?

Comment: A good approach is superposition. You can determine what Vout will be when either V1 or V2 is present then simply add those Vout values.

Answer (score 1):

The common node of the two resistors in the left has a voltage of 0 volt. Based on this, you can calculate the current through the two resistors. This current has to flow to another branch. It can't go into OPAMP pin since it has ideally infinite resistance. Therefore, it has to go through *Rf*. You can calculate the output voltage by this current and consequently the gain.

Answer (score 0):

An extremely useful tool for analyzing linear circuits with multiple inputs (voltage and/or current sources) like this one is the [superposition theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superposition_theorem). To use it, you find the gain for each input one at a time (with all other inputs turned off), then sum the individual gains. Other inputs are turned off by replacing voltage sources with a short circuit and current sources with an open circuit.

In this case, you would set \$V_2 = 0\$ and find \$V_{\text{out}}\$ due to \$V_1\$ (call it \$V_{\text{out1}}\$). Then set \$V_1 = 0\$ and find \$V_{\text{out}}\$ due to \$V_2\$ (call it \$V_{\text{out2}}\$). Finally, \$V_{\text{out}}= V_{\text{out1}} + V_{\text{out2}}\$.

Answer (score 0):

As Jonk is hinting with his comment, this particular circuit is called an **inverting summing amplifier**. A node equation at the inverting input and using the concept of a **virtual short** reveals the following relationship
$$V_o = -V_1-V_2 = -1.5\text{V}+0.780\text{V}=-0.720\text{V} $$

I will leave it to you to find the node equation the symbolically. If you are unsure how to do this please ask.

Hopefully you can see why the name for this circuit is very fitting.